# Microsoft Graph 'Unable to read JSON request payload' error when inviting users to Azure AD in Python with Requests

Tags: python-requests, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to automate inviting users to an Azure AD using the MS Graph API but get an 'Unable to read JSON request payload' error.

I'm pulling data from a ticketing system, retrieving the current AAD users and diff-ing both. Then I'll be pushing the new ones into the AAD and updating them to include them in an Attendees AD Security group.

I created a Python Azure Function that calls the Graph API with Requests :

```
def insert_users(users_emails):

    logging.info('Inserting new users in AAD')

    token                       =   generate_auth_token()

    users_emails    =   users_emails[:2]
    added_attendees =   []

    for email in users_emails:

        req_body        =   {
                                    "invitedUserEmailAddress"       :   email
                                ,   "inviteRedirectUrl"             :   "https://myapp.com"
                            }

        body_length     =   sys.getsizeof(req_body)

        req_headers     =   {
                                    'Authorization'     :   'Bearer {0}'.format(token)
                                ,   'Content-Type'      :   'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                                ,   'Content-Length'    :   str(body_length)
                            }

        response    =   requests.post(
                                'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations'
                            ,   headers =   req_headers
                            ,   data    =   req_body
                        )

        response    =   response.json()

        logging.info(response)

        added_attendees.append(email)

        return added_attendees
```

The Graph API sends back the following error message :

```
{'error': 
    {'code':    'BadRequest', 
                'message': 'Unable to read JSON request payload. Please ensure Content-Type header is set and payload is of valid JSON format.',
                'innerError': 
                    {'request-id': '4ff5332d-d280-4b0d-9e04-a7359ab0e2fb', 'date': '2020-05-27T14:51:18'}
    }
}
```

I tried adding the charset to the Content-Type header but it won't work. I read someplace the Content-Length could be useful so I added it too, to no avail.

Tests run ok in Postman and I'm already performing a POST request against the Azure AD API to get an Access Token so the Requests JSON body is parsed fine then. I also tried using single or double quotes in the JSON payload but it didn't work either.

My take is something is misinterpreted by the Graph API but I can't figure out what.

Thanks forward for your help !

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution. Instead of passing a data argument to the request.post method, I passed a json= argument

```
    response    =   requests.post(
                            'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations'
                        ,   json={'invitedUserEmailAddress':email,'inviteRedirectUrl':'https://myapp.com'}
                        ,   headers =   req_headers
                    )
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I got the same error for different situation and was able to solve it after reading your post and other similar posts. My issue was with posting emojis/special character  in Microsoft Teams and was able to resolve it by switching the library. I posted my solution here in case someone ran to the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56731805/badrequest-error-while-using-sendmail-request-of-microsoft-graph-api/70962710#70962710